# how to list files in a folder using bash scripting

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory

I am just getting started with bash scripting and I was trying to write a simple script where I can list all the files with a certain extension using a bash script. I mostly code in Python or Matlab so I am very used to setting the address of the folder and using the cd function to change path to that folder and getting the list of the files in that folder. I was trying to do that with bash and I am not what I am doing wrong. For example, I am trying to list all the subfolders in a folder with the following address `"/home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start"`

So far i have tried

```
cd "/home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start"
```

and it hasn't done much when I run it from terminal.

How would I cd into it and list its folders?

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: What sort of errors you get when you try to cd ? Is the path correct ? Are there any special characters that should be in any folder names ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
ls -l -d /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/
```

- `*/` looks for directories
- `-d` says do not print the content of those directories.

Comment: Related:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981439/reading-filenames-into-an-array

This post was also another option I explored with success.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical use case for shell globbing (pathname expansion):

```
/home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/
```

Here i have used `*/` which will match any file (`*`) under `/home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/`, that is a directory (trailing `/`).

If you want to operate on these later, better put the result of expansion in an array (works in a similar manner to Python `list`, both are 0-indexed too):

```
directories=( /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/ )
```

then you can reference the array and it's elements using usual array manipulation operators.

OTOH, if you want the list, use `echo`/`printf`/`ls` -- whatever suits you the best:

```
printf '%s\n' /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/
echo /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/
ls -ld /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/
```

for any directory name with embedded newline, lookout for tailing `/` as name ending marker.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the response. I am trying to do something along the lines of using
directories=( /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start/*/ )

However, when i use this way, i get the following error
bash: /testBash.sh: No such file or directory

I want to store the folders and then see if they have any subfolders which might have files of my interest

Answer (score 0):

You can list that "folder2Start" file with:

```
ls -la /home/user012/Desktop/folder2Start
```

Maybe I'm too late but the question still active, I hope it can be useful for you.